# eclipse device view not detect my galaxy note

Tags: android

eclipse device view not detect my galaxy note .
I can open the phone's folder from the computer as well I have installed the usb drivers from Samsung website 
Still the device not appear after dubbing

Please note : 
-I have enabled the USB  debugging in my phone

Comment: which os ? Linux or Windows ?

Comment: Did you just select usb mass storage as you said you could open the phone folder? Because if you select that, you could only transfer the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the driver download kies samsung ( type kies samsung on gooogle ) 
install it and then try

Answer (score 1):

Check your Device Manager and if you see yellow mark next to your device , update your device driver manually.
browse your computer for driver software then pick from list of device drivers

Comment: yes its yellow  but it could not find the driver , could you provide me with the driver

Comment: find it manually and from the list i think its driver should be Samsung Android ADB interface if you installed Samsung drivers before